# Ruby: Why don't I get nil when using the safe navigation operator

Tags: ruby

I have read about the safe operator. The way I understand it, is that it will call a method on an object but we get nil if that object doesn't exist.

```
2.3.1 :001 > 123&.to_s
 => "123"
```

But when I try using it when calling a method on an object that doesn't exist, I get:

```
2.3.1 :003 > foo&.to_s
NameError: undefined local variable or method `foo' for main:Object
Did you mean?  fork
    from (irb):3
    from /Users/duncan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

What am I doing wrong? Have I misunderstood the & operator?

Answer (score 2):

It's not working if your variable is not defined. You can use `defined?` and **Lazy evaluation**

example:

```
defined?(foo) ? foo&.to_s : nil
#=> nil
foo = 3
defined?(foo) ? foo&.to_s : nil
#=> "3"
```

Comment: `defined?` is not a method, but a language construct

Answer (score 1):

The safe navigator operator saves you from calling methods on a NilClass object but the receiver has to be defined. A nonsense but useful examples

```
a = [-3, -2, -1]
a.find_index(-3).zero? # true
a.find_index(5)&.zero? # nil
a.find_index(5).zero? # NoMethodError: undefined method `zero?' for nil:NilClass
```

`to_s` is a bad example because `nil.to_s` is an empty string. Let's use `split`

```
"asd-lol".split("-") # ["asd", "lol"]
nil&.split("-") # nil
nil.split("-") # NoMethodError: undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass
```